# Typescript: Getting the entire object under one property after initializing the interface in my component class

Tags: angular, primeng

I am getting the entire object from my model under one property after initializing it in my component class.

Еhis is my model/interface:

````js
export interface CompanyDropDownItem {
    CompanyAn: number;
    CompanyCode: string;
    CompanyName: string;
    Inactive: boolean;
}

This is in my class implementing OnInit:

```typescript
companyDropdown: CompanyDropDownItem[];

selectedCompanyDropdown: CompanyDropDownItem = 
    {
     CompanyAn: 0,
     CompanyName: '',
     CompanyCode: '',
     Inactive:false
    };
````

This is the `edit` form view where the values `CompanyAn`, `CompanyName` and `CompanyCode` have to update by `onChange`:

```html
<label for="CompanyName">Company</label>
<p-dropdown #selectedNewEmployee name="CompanyName" [options]="companyDropdown" placeholder="Select Company"  optionLabel="CompanyName" appendTo="body" [virtualScroll]="true" [itemSize]="20" [filter]="true" [showClear]="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedCompanyDropdown (onChange)="getCompanyDetails(selectedCompanyDropdown)"></p-dropdown>

<div>
    <p-button label="Save" icon="pi pi-check" (onClick)="onSaveEmployee(selectedNewEmployee.value)"></p-button>
</div>
```

This is `getCompanyDetails()` - `WebEmployeeDetails` is a bigger interface where the values are being inserted:

```js
getCompanyDetails(WebEmployeeDetail: CompanyDropDownItem) {
    
   // PASSING IN ALL THE PROPERTIES FROM THE COMPANY CLASS
   this.selectedEmployee.CompanyAn = WebEmployeeDetail.CompanyAn ;
   this.selectedEmployee.CompanyCode = WebEmployeeDetail.CompanyCode;
   this.selectedEmployee.CompanyName = WebEmployeeDetail.CompanyName;
    
   // CHECKING THE VALUES ARE CHANGING WITH EACH CHANGE IN THE DROPDOWN
   console.log('New CompanyAn is: ',this.selectedEmployee.CompanyAn);
   console.log('New Company Code is: ',this.selectedEmployee.CompanyCode);
   console.log('New Company Name is: ',this.selectedEmployee.CompanyName);
}
```

Finally, this is `onSaveEmployee()`:

```js
onSaveEmployee(WebEmployeeDetail: WebEmployeeDetail): void {
    
    this.div_visible = true; // progress bar start.
        this.EmployeeService.onUpdateEmployee(WebEmployeeDetail)
            .subscribe(
                (data: WebEmployeeDetail) => setTimeout(()=>{ this.div_visible = false }, 1000, console.log(`${WebEmployeeDetail.PeopleId} updated succesfully`, data)),
                (err: any) => console.log(err)
                      )
```

The problem is as you can see the image using the Chrome Console link I'm getting the entire `selectedCompanyDropDown` object under the `CompanyName` property.

How can I only pass the `CompanyName` property instead of the entire object?

[Chrome Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9nwl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to receive the attribute from the object, you need to change the optionValue attribute, like this:

```html
<p-dropdown #selectedNewEmployee name="CompanyName" optionValue="CompanyName" [options]="companyDropdown" placeholder="Select Company"  optionLabel="CompanyName" appendTo="body" [virtualScroll]="true" [itemSize]="20" [filter]="true" [showClear]="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedCompanyDropdown (onChange)="getCompanyDetails(selectedCompanyDropdown)"></p-dropdown>
```